Proverb request - for counseling newly married couples
Is there a proverb in English to advise married couples to ignore small arguments?
In a South Indian language there is a proverb:
When pots and pans meet, there would be some noise..
It implies that conflicts are inevitable when two people with distinct personalities get together. The proverb could also indicate that when a husband and wife are arguing, elders or other people shouldn't get involved.
I know the English proverb:
"Empty vessels make the most noise." But it has a totally different meaning.

Not exactly a proverb, but people sometimes say, "The honeymoon is over," to mean that you've passed through the initial euphoria when you see no wrongs in your partner into more normal life where friction happens. This can be used for a marriage (where there was a literal honeymoon) or metaphorically in other situations - after starting a new job or, very often, after a new politician takes office.

My late grandmother used to say "Every pot has a lid"  but the meaning was that there's a suitable partner out there somewhere for every person.
You could elaborate on it, as it's in the public domain :-)

Every pot has a lid but the two will make a clatter.


Do not let the sun go down on your anger is actually from the Bible (Ephesians 4:26), but it became a sort of proverb relating to all kinds of domestic disputes (it's used in Little Women of a quarrel between sisters). I'm sure I've seen similar advice given to couples. It means that you shouldn't let feelings of resentment carry over to the next day.

These may not be proverbs but are good, from marriage.com:
Enter married life with realistic expectations.
Don’t sweat the small stuff, and when conflicts arise drop the blame game and adopt a problem-solving approach.
Accept that your spouse is weird and
accept your partner the way they are.

In my experience, in England, what goes on inside a marriage is not regarded as suitable for discussion or comment.
In days gone by, people (mostly the women) had to accept whatever came their way.
In modern times, people generally spend a long time getting to know each other before marrying, and often live together. By the time they actually marry, they generally have a pretty good idea what they are getting into.

But proverbs evolved long before this was the case.

Couples in the UK are also seeking marriage counselor's help.
During couples counselling, you and your partner will meet with a specialist to talk through and explore the problems you're both facing.  https://nowyouretalkingtherapy.co.uk › relationship › counselling
Relationship Counselling - Relationship Specialists
2.
https://www.sdhcounselling.co.uk
Marriage Counselling & Support
Marriage
3. angelomussoni.org
https://www.angelomussoni.org › couples › online
Dr. Angelo Mussoni - Marriage counseling -
